# Identifying John Morgan, son of Thomas D. Morgan (1809-1870)?

Tags: united-states, dna, relationship-analysis, south-carolina

I have a real dilemma.   I have found a DNA link to the Thomas Morgan (1791-1860) family through Frances Denira "Fanny" Morgan (1821-1899), daughter of Benjamin Francis Morgan (1762-1835), who was the son of Thomas and Isabella Chitta Morgan.

After researching back I don't find in Benjamin Francis' line any John Wesley Morgan (1831-1901) who was my great grandfather, but I do find a John Morgan (abt. 1830-?)

Who is the son of Thomas D. Morgan (1809-1870), grandson of John Morgan (1754-1811) and great grandson of Thomas and Isabella Morgan i.e. how do I prove Thomas Morgan's John and my John Wesley are the same person?

John Morgan is mentioned in Thomas' Will but only as John.  Same with census.

Uncle Benjamin Francis' brother is John Morgan f/o Thomas D. Morgan.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Please try to ask a single focussed question rather than two.  I am going to edit out your second question to try and focus this on your first.  Feel free to ask the DNA question as a new question.

Comment: If your great grandfather (John Wesley Morgan) is the same as John Morgan, then on your great grandfather's marriage record it should say that his father is Thomas D Morgan. This should be no bother at all because you know your great grandmother's name to search for the right record.

Comment: Where was your John Morgan likely to have been born?  Do you have his baptism and/or marriage/death/burial record?  You have a tag for South Carolina, but make no mention of that state or any other state (or country) in your question.  Geography can play a big part when trying to establish identity.

Comment: I think this will depend on the jurisdiction in which John Wesley Morgan married because fathers are not always named.

Comment: @PolyGeo perhaps not. If Kay48 specified the geographical area in which he is looking we may be able to better help

Comment: Downvoted initially because I was (mistakenly) thinking of Georgia marriage records, which do not name the parents during this period. However, since we don't know the locality, I can't agree with your assessment that finding a marriage record "should be no bother at all".  Please refrain from making this kind of assessment in answers. i am willing to reconsider upvoting after the answer has been edited and improved.

https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/South_Carolina_Vital_Records#Marriage_Records

Comment: Your question could be improved by adding a source list (with better citations than simply "I have so-and-so's census) so we can see what you  already have on hand.  As @PolyGeo says, knowing the specific locality is very important, since many records from this period will be kept at the local level.

Comment: The Marriage license and certificate only list Cherokee county, Georgia as the place of both.  Lots of "Ordinaries" listed (which are like county clerks). There are two John Morgans in 1850 in Pickens county, South Carolina.  One is the s/o Elijah and Polly Morgan the other is the s/o Thomas D. and Lorinda (?) Morgan.

Comment: The Thomas I mentioned is Thomas D. grandson of Thomas and son of John Morgan.

Comment: John Wesley Morgan was born in South Carolina 13 Dec., 1831.  He married his first wife Jane Elvira Dorris in 1854 in Cherokee county, Georgia.  She died 25 Aug., 1866 in Colbert county, Alabama.  He married his second wife Rebecca Jane Whitlock the 15th of September, 1867 in Colbert county, Alabama (this is my line).  She died in 1892 and he died in 1901 in Parker county, Texas.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score -1):

John Wesley Morgan:
https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/21930441/john-wesley-morgan

1st wife:  Jane Elvira Morgan, née Dorris, died from picking peaches in a tree, slipped and caught her ankle in a branch and (asphyxiated?) died because it took too long to find her according to our family story;

John Wesley was distraught, remarried:
Rebecca Jane Whitlock, called Rebecca in the Morgan family Bible in the possession of my cousin, a retired math professor at Oklahoma State University, Stillwater;

John Wesley and Rebecca moved to Texas where both are buried.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH:SE.  Perhaps you could edit your answer to explain why you think your John Wesley Morgan is the John Morgan the OP is asking about?